# Add OnMouseHover or Click function for cloned gameObject?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I learned somehow now.

Btw I am struggling with a problem.

The problem is, I've created the clone GameObject using Instantiate and it works well. But I want to implement the OnMouseHover or Click for every cloned object to show a pop-up. How can I refer to the clicked object which I've created at runtime? Thank you!

```
void Awake(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myPdfPrefabClone = Instantiate(myPdfPrefab, new Vector3(x, 0, x), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        myPdfPrefabClone.name = "" + x;
        Debug.Log(myPdfPrefabClone.transform.position);

        Debug.Log("name " + myPdfPrefabClone.name);

        x = x + 2.5F;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check how to use raycast for detecting objects with mouse, when you achieve this, you can enable/disable "popup" gameObjects within a function

Comment: See the `ClickDetector` script from the duplicate. Now, all you have to do is `myPdfPrefabClone.AddComponent<ClickDetector>();`. The `OnPointerEnter` function should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @Programmer I've assigned the scripts for clone GameObjects at runtime. I just tested out the network call and other color changing. It's working but the not detecting the tab or click functions.

Comment: Didn't work anything but I've added a **script** and **SphereCollider** while cloning the **GameObject**. After that only the tab function working for every cloned object.

Comment: When you try an answer an it doesn't work, add EDIT to your question and then include he new code to show what you have tried.

Comment: Finally, I've solved the problem. But there is no way to explain since the question marked as duplicate.